# excel não está reconhecendo os números do intervalo

Tags: microsoft-excel

Esta é a planilha para calculo do imposto devido em função do faturamento:
Receita Bruta Total nos últimos 12 meses

```
         A               B             C          D
1                                   Alíquota  Faturamento
2            -       180.000,00     4,50%
3     180.000,01     360.000,00     6,54%      350.000,00
4     360.000,01     540.000,00     7,70%
5     540.000,01     720.000,00     8,49%
6     720.000,01     900.000,00     8,97%
7     900.000,01     1.080.000,00   9,78%
8    1.080.000,01    1.260.000,00   10,26%
9    1.260.000,01    1.440.000,00   10,76%
```

Fiz a seguinte fórmula: `=se(A3<=D3<=B3|C3|0)`
O que está errado?

Comment: Enviei a tabela formatada, mas saiu todo o formato e assim fica dificil entender o que quero.

Comment: Pronto, formatado. Quando for adicionar algo e quer que mantenha a formatação, selecione o trecho e clique em `{}` :)

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema seja essa expressão

> A3<=D3<=B3

que está mal formatada.
Não é possível fazer múltiplas expressões de combinação, você pode usar os conectivo lógico "E". ([link](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/E-Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-E-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9))
  A expressão correta cacho que seria:

> (A3<=D3)& (D3<=B3)

ou

> (A3<=D3) E (D3<=B3)